# Small quiet zone with Zxing when specified 0

Tags: java, zxing

I'm currently using the ZXing Library to decode QR Codes. Additional I'm displaying the created QR Code on the screen with JavaFx. I'd like to create QR Codes without quiet zone, so I set the margin to zero. However I realized that when I create a QR Code with Error Correction Level L there is still a small quiet zone. Here is a picture displaying the result.

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH94O.png)

Now the strange thing is the same QR Code with Error Correction Level H has no quiet zone.

Here is my code for creating the QR Codes.

```
private BufferedImage QRCodeGenerator(String content, int height, int width) {
Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hintMap = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);

hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0);

QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;

try {
    BitMatrix byteMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, hintMap);
    bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    bufferedImage.createGraphics();

    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        if (byteMatrix.get(i, j)) {
        graphics.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
        }
    }
    }
} catch (WriterException e) {

}

return bufferedImage;
}
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Please try the following:
BitMatrix byteMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 0, 0, hintMap);
I only checked it against the current .Net port but if no height and width is specified zxing should use the smallest possible values. And, of course, the BufferedImage has to be initialized with the sizes of the BitMatrix.

Comment: Your suggestion results in a very very small QR Code on the top left of a white square (the `BufferedImage`).